# remove html entities using simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

the markup is terrible, how can I get rid of the grey part? no class, no id.

I used simple html dom parser and this line of code to reach to the 'dd'

```
$lyric = $lyricDOM->find('#fsZ dl', 0)->find('dd',0); // lyric block
```

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the font tags? If so, a simple regex might be the best bet.

Comment: If you go to http://regexpal.com/ - You can put this content in the data input and use the regex-input on the site to make a regular expression. The site will highlight whay you've selected so you can learn it by trying it.

Comment: @girlwithglasses for example?

Comment: @Onovar: I'm not sure that's a good idea. Manipulating HTML with regular expressions can turn into a bit of a mess quickly. [Here's several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22don%27t+use%22+regexp+parse+html) to that effect.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for those answers, learning every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `innertext` and `outertext` functions in a callback to extract and replace the `<font>` tags while parsing. Short example:

```
$html = str_get_html("<dd><font style='font-size:14px;'>red<br>green<br>blue</font></dd>");

// Write a function with parameter "$element"
function my_callback($element) {
    // This will be called every time the 'font' element is encountered
    if ($element->tag=='font')
    $element->outertext = $element->innertext;
}

// Register the callback function
$html->set_callback('my_callback');

// Callback function will be invoked while dumping
echo $html . "\n";
```

Result:

```
<dd>red<br>green<br>blue</dd>
```

See the http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm for a full explanation of `innertext`, `outertext`, and callbacks. You can expand the callback to include other elements that you want to ignore during parsing.